# How to subscribe several subscribers to Observable or Flowable?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

In Hello World example there is one subscriber

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Flowable.just("Hello world").subscribe(System.out::println);
   }
```

How to make two or more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subscribe multiple subsctibers to any observable/flowable. Just repeat `subscribe` call as many times as you need.

```
Flowable<String> source = Flowable.just("Hello world");
source.subscribe(System.out::println);
source.subscribe(System.out::println);
...
```

There is difference in *hot* and *cold* observables in the way they handle such multiple subscriptions.

*Cold* observables/flowables re-request items from source for every new subscriber. For example, `Flowable.fromCallable(c)` will invoke `c` every time it is subscribed to.

*Hot* observables/flowables share same source subscription with all subscribers, i.e. they do not request new items from source for every new subscriber. New items get propagated to all currently subscribed subscribers.

Comment: I don't know why. But I need a share() operator if I wrap onClick into Observable. Otherwise only one subscriber will get the call.

Comment: @PhoenixWang It depends on how you wrap it. Can't tell without looking into code. Try posting it as a new question here on SO.

Comment: Thx. I guess i figure it out. I tried RxBinding and normal wrap with create like: Observable.create(e -> btn.setOnClickListener(v -> e.onNext(""))); They works the same. Only the last subscriber can receive the call. I read the source code of Observable. So basically in Observable only one Observer at a time can receive the onNext call because of the implementation of subscribeActual() method.

Comment: @PhoenixWang When using *cold* observable (such as `Observable.create`) you invoke `btn.setOnClickListener` for every new subscriber. In case `btn.setOnClickListener` removes previously set listener, then previous subscribers won't receive messages. Try using `btn.addOnClickListener` if there is one.

Comment: Still not entirely clear on this. It seems like an `Observable` (especially a hot one) would have to maintain a list of current `Subscribers` to handle multiple subscriptions. True? When it wants to emit an item (or an error or a completion), wouldn't it have to iterate through all Subscribers and call each one's `onNext()`? Is this the expected behavior of any Observable? Or is support for multiple Subscribers an optional feature? How should it be documented?