# How to create my own hot Observable from scratch?

Tags: java, rx-java

How to create my own hot Observable from scratch?

I would like create my own function, returning observable, returning locations:

```
public static Observable<Location> locationObservable(Context context, String provider, long minTime, float minDistance) {
```

This is for Android. It is recommended to use `Observable.create()` for this purposes, but [example shows just passing constant list of integers](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/create.html#collapseRxJava%C2%A01%E2%80%A4x) to each subscriber, which is not hot.

If I do something else here, for example, remember a list of subscribers, then how will I implement unsubscribing and many other features?

I.e. absolutely no idea is what to do inside `Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>()` implementation?

Answer (score 2):

Generally to create *hot observable* you use some kind of `Subject`: `PublishSubject`, `BehaviorSubject`, etc.

See examples for `BehaviorSubject` [here](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html).

```
class LocationService {
    private Subject<Location> subject = BehaviorSubject.create();

    Observable<Location> locationObservable(...) {
        return subject;
    }

    void onNewLocationListener(Location newLocation) {
        subject.onNext(newLocation);
    }
}
```

Comment: But subject is write-enabled, i.e. anyone can post additional locations to it. How to avoid this?

Comment: @Dims That is why it is declared `private`. And when I return it, I cast it to `Observable`.

Comment: @Dims You can always make a wrapper class with all sorts of access controls and validators.

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to write your own, at least until you are proficient with the existing ones and need a peculiar caching/emission pattern not covered by the default 5 (Async, Behavior, Publish, Replay, Unicast).

I have a 3 part series on the subject (pun intended) if you really want to:

- [Part 1](http://akarnokd.blogspot.hu/2015/06/subjects-part-1.html)
- [Part 2](http://akarnokd.blogspot.hu/2015/09/subjects-part-2.html)
- [Part 3](http://akarnokd.blogspot.hu/2015/09/subjects-part-3-final.html)

Comment: I don't want to write my own either. I would like to "create", i.e. instantiate. How to do that?

Comment: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/1.x/javadoc/rx/subjects/PublishSubject.html look for the example section in the Javadoc of the subjects.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this wonderful example taken directly from Realm's [`RealmObservableFactory`](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm/realm-library/src/main/java/io/realm/rx/RealmObservableFactory.java#L67):

```
@Override
public Observable<Realm> from(Realm realm) {
    final RealmConfiguration realmConfig = realm.getConfiguration();
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Realm>() { // create new observable
        @Override
        public void call(final Subscriber<? super Realm> subscriber) { // this is executed on `subscribeOn(Scheduler)`
            final Realm observableRealm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfig);
            final RealmChangeListener<Realm> listener = new RealmChangeListener<Realm>() {
                @Override
                public void onChange(Realm realm) {
                    if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) { // always check if subscriber is unsubscribed!
                        subscriber.onNext(observableRealm);
                    }
                }
            };
            subscriber.add(Subscriptions.create(new Action0() { // add unsubscription first! thread specified by unsubscribeOn(Scheduler)
                @Override
                public void call() {
                    observableRealm.removeChangeListener(listener); // remove listener
                    observableRealm.close();
                }
            }));
            observableRealm.addChangeListener(listener); // add listener
            subscriber.onNext(observableRealm); // initial value
        }
    });
}
```

And read the comments, it's a pretty good example.

Comment: Will it be possible to unsubscribe from this clew?

Comment: This one is not *hot*. It invokes `Realm.getInstance()` for every new subscriber.

Comment: @yaroslawStavnichiy what would make it hot, then? O_O

Comment: @EpicPandaForce There are lots of articles about hot and cold observables. See about important difference here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41824445/697313